# Using template for array constructor as a function return type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm a little new to the template function in c++ and encounter a problem that I cannot find any result by googling.

Trying to use a template here for generating different dimensions of arrays. The code is shown below:

```
 template <size_t T> 
 vector<array<float, T>> poissonSample(size_t T, float r) {
    array<float, T> x_min, x_max;

    return samples;
  }
```

The definition of the function seems fine, however, when I try to call the function with something like:

```
poissonSample(4, 0.3f);
```

The compiler will report "no instance of function template matches the argument list.

[image]

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code I compiled at onlinegdb.com

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;


template <size_t T> 
vector<array<float, T>> poissonSample(size_t T, float r);

int main()
{
    auto res = poissonSample(4, 1.0f)
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the full text of the error messages:

```
main.cpp:17:46: error: declaration of ‘size_t T’ shadows template parameter
 vector<array<float, T>> poissonSample(size_t T, float r);
                                              ^
main.cpp:16:11: note: template parameter ‘T’ declared here
 template <size_t T>
           ^~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:21:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘poissonSample(int, float)’
     auto res = poissonSample(4, 1.0f)
                                     ^
main.cpp:17:25: note: candidate: template std::vector > poissonSample(size_t, float)
 vector<array<float, T>> poissonSample(size_t T, float r);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:17:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:21:37: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
     auto res = poissonSample(4, 1.0f)
```

As you can see, the root problem is that the `size_t T` in the function parameters and `size_t T` in template parameters are unrelated. One is a compile-time construct, the other is a run-time construct.

The secondary problem is

```
main.cpp:17:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

The compiler cannot figure out your T.

The correct usage would be:

```
template <size_t T> 
vector<array<float, T>> poissonSample(float r);

int main()
{
    auto res = poissonSample<4>(1.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

(this gives only a linker error, provide your own implementation)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solves my confusion about the use of using a template for parameters rather than types.

Comment: Well, there is a new problem that when I try to use an argument of a function to generate this possion function: `poissonSample<arg>(r)`, the system reports ` 'this' cannot be used in a  constant expression`.

Comment: Templates (including std::array) cannot be used that way. Everything must be known at compile time. You'll need to change your approach.

Comment: yeah, realize the issue is the array. array size has to be known at compile time.